Database table prefix different between wp-config.php and in database
I'm completely updating this quesion because I've discovered new facts about the problem.  My wp-config.php has the line $table_prefix  = 'wp75_';.  The plugin WP-Optimize also shows the tables with that prefix and says there are 55 tables.
However, the actual database, as seen in phpMyAdmin, has 163 tables.  There are three versions of almost all the tables: one set with the wp75_ prefix, one set with wp3563b3 prefix, and a set with wp471cb8.
I checked the posts table and saw that the versions have different contents. wp75_posts contains 10.7 MiB, wp3563b3posts has 11.7 MiB, and wp471cb8posts has 12.7 MiB.  wp75_posts is up to date, with the most recent post yesterday; the others most recent are in January and April.  I think it is the correct one.  Maybe the others have more because I since deleted some things.
The site works fine, but I'm concerned that something is happening to my database.  I have no idea where those extra table versions came from, but it seems to have happened twice.
What's the most likely thing that created those tables?  I wonder if it somehow happens when I create a staging version of the site for testing (but the staging site has a separate database).  Should I simply delete all the tables with the funny prefixes?
The image below has the table list filtered with 'posts', showing three different versions of the tables.


I'd check all the tables you have on that install. You may have 2 different sets of wordpress tables one database.

Thanks, but all the tables have the same prefix.

There is a staging version of the site too, but it has a separate database.  All the tables in it have the same prefix as the main site's db, and the staging's wp-config.php has the same prefix as it does in the main site.

You're missing something.  Maybe $table_prefix = 'wp_'; is listed 2x in your wp-config file?

Good idea, but no, there is only one occurrence of table_prefix: $table_prefix  = 'wp75_'; And the prefix that shows in the tables in phpMyAdmin does not appear in the config file at all. But I'm sure you're right, I'm missing something.

Maybe trying changing something in the table you believe is connected and see if it reflects to the site. (ie options table change the site title or something).

Now we're getting somewhere.  Please see edited question for new information.

@rudtek, you were right from the beginning.  Somehow I missed that there were multiple versions of the tables.  Please see rewritten question for the real situation.

Problem solved, but really due to @rudtek suggestions, so if you put an answer I will  select it.  This thread talked about backup plugins that create database 'snapshots' by duplicating tables with different prefixes.  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/database-with-repeating-tables-preceded-by-6-letter-prefix-keeps-growing-in-size/ Turns out I had done this with WPvivid Backup twice, without realizing that 'snapshot' meant duplicating tables.  I deleted the snapshots in WPvivid and problem solved.

WordPress can only use the tables with the same prefix as listed in the wp-config.php file. Many times when a database has been used for sometime it will hold several version of the site in the same database by adding different table prefixes to the site versions.
This is likely what you are seeing. It seems a backup system or an older version of the site made those other tables but it would be the tables with the $table_prefix  = 'wp75_'; that are holding the data for your live site.
